# How to get a mean from data.frame?

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I have a data.frame, which i got from this:
    `data <- ldply(xmlToList("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/a025z100205.xml"),data.frame)`

I create a list like this :

```
list <- data[[6]]
```

then I deleted NA values

```
list <- list[!is.na(list)]
```

And I got this

```
[1] 0,0900 2,9915 2,5851 0,3850 2,7805 2,0566 2,1043 4,0921 1,4918 2,7837
[11] 4,7009 0,3723 3,3450 0,1561 0,5496 0,2615 2,3211 0,4987 0,4005 0,5589
[21] 0,9894 2,0923 1,9688 1,1851 5,7733 0,0643 0,2271 0,3884 1,5965 0,8687
[31] 0,0981 3,1673 0,2557 0,4384 4,5657
35 Levels: 0,0900 2,9915 2,5851 0,3850 2,7805 2,0566 2,1043 4,0921 ... 4,5657
```

But I can't get the mean from this list. It is because of levels? How can I do this?

Comment: how you tried to convert your data to `numeric`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` of 'list' is `factor` due to the non-numeric component (`,`).  When there is a non-numeric element in a column, by creating a `data.frame`, the default option is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`.  We can include the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` inside `data.frame` to get the character column, but still the `,` should be replaced.  Assuming that it is meant for decimal,   we replace it with `.` using `sub`, convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` and get the `mean`.

```
mean(as.numeric(sub(',', '.', list)))
```

#### EDIT

After reading the data using the OP's code, I understand that it is the 4th and 6th columns that are numeric (but all the columns are 'factor' class).  If you are interested only in the 6th column, do as above, but if you need to get the `mean` of 4th and 6th, use `sapply`

```
 sapply(data[c(4,6)], function(x) 
       mean(as.numeric(sub(',', '.', x)), na.rm=TRUE))
 #przelicznik kurs_sredni 
 #298.00000     1.66298
```

Or

```
m1 <-  `dim<-`(as.numeric(sub(',', '.', as.matrix(data[c(4,6)]))), 
                dim(data[c(4,6)]))
colMeans(m1, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 298.00000   1.66298
```

NOTE: It is better not to name objects with function names.